# display most commented (on facebook) "article"

Tags: django, facebook

i have set of articles on my website where people can comment using facebook.
The fix is I have to find the most commented article and show, say 5 of them, on webpage.
I have tried looking into facebook api, and googled it out for 2-3 days without having any luck.please help

Answer (score 0):

You can query this info from the Facebook API - I'll explain the process to do it, but I'm not a django expert, so you'll need to turn this into Python.

Basically, you need to grab the URLs for each of your articles and hit the Graph API requesting the comments and a summary of them for that URL like this: https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=YOUR-URL&summary=1

Change the YOUR-URL part of the above to the link you want to check. You can even specify more than one link at at time if you like: https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=YOUR-URL1,YOUR-URL2&summary=1

So if you query the example.com comments:

Hit this URL https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://example.com/comments&summary=1

You should get back some JSON data which looks like this (I trimmed the middle bit):

```
{
   "http://example.com/comments": {
      "comments": {
         "data": [
...
         ],
         "paging": {
            "cursors": {
               "after": "NDc4OQ==",
               "before": "NDgyMg=="
            },
            "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/10150107083136229/comments?summary=1&limit=25&after=NDc4OQ\u00253D\u00253D"
         },
         "summary": {
            "order": "ranked",
            "total_count": 4822
         }
      }
   }
}
```

In the "summary" section you can see there is a total_count which is the number of comments made on that URL.

So your process will be:

- Loop through all the links you want to check
- Hit the Facebook Graph API for that URL Extract the total_count response in the JSON and
  store it (perhaps in a table)
- Order the results on the number of comments descending, limiting to
  only the first 5 results (if you're using MySQL then something like
  SELECT * FROM whatever ORDER BY total_count DESC LIMIT 5)